# Not able to set cpuset atribute to vcpu element in instance xml

Tags: openstack, libvirt, openstack-nova

In relation to [this](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/nova/+spec/instance-vcpu-pin) patch, I have not been able to use it. I mean, as it has been merged so it is there in my code, but I am not sure how to enable/use it?

This particular patch adds cpuset attribute to the vcpu element of the instance's xml file. I cant figure out how exactly I can do that for a particular instance. Suppose I want to pin pcpu 2 and 3, so the vcpu entry would be

```
<vcpu cpuset="2,3">2</vcpu>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this patch does not allow you to do pinning on a per-instance basis. Instead, it allows you to specify a subset of physical CPUs, guaranteeing that the instances will only run on those CPUs. You specify the CPUs with the vcpu_pin_set config option in `/etc/nova/nova.conf`. Here's an [example from the patch:](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/26363/13/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py)

```
vcpu_pin_set=4-12,^8,15
```

Presumably, this would ensure that all instances only run on CPUs 4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,15

Comment: Yeah, it does look like that. But the issue is it's not working. I mean I did add the entry in nova.conf. But still, it's not restricting the use of cpus. Btw thanks for the explanation.